# Error while installing Sitecore 9.1: Service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer' cannot be stopped

Tags: xconnect

[image: Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer error in command window]

I am facing an error related to service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer' while installing Sitecore 9.1.

Comment: What happens if you try to manually stop the service? Have you tried uninstalling and then reinstalling again?

Comment: @MarcelGruber Can you check that you have provided the correct solr Path? Also check if the path is given without the # at the end of solr URL?

Comment: Error messages should be included as text, never images

Answer (score 2):

Ensure you have configured the following options using the Windows features-`Turn Windows features on or off`, and rerun the setup.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It helps...

Comment: @Prashant B, it helps you, vote and accepts the answer.